# why do i keep getting emails from my form?

Tags: php, forms, email

I recently made a form for my webpage, but i keep getting emails from my form. Even though i don't send the form i keep getting emails.

And if i do submit my form i get 2 or 3 emails. 1 with the information of my form, and 2 with no information.

php code:

```
<?php
//reciever
$to      = 'julius.kroon@gmail.com';
//subject
$subject = 'new costumer';
//form information
$title = "";
$name = "";
$companyname = "";
$mail = "";
$extrapages = "";
$sow = "";
if(isset($_POST['title'])){ $title = $_POST['title']; } //title
if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; } //name
if(isset($_POST['companyname'])){ $companyname = $_POST['companyname']; }          //company name
if(isset($_POST['mail'])){ $mail = $_POST['mail']; } //email
if(isset($_POST['extrapages'])){ $extrapages = $_POST['extrapages']; } //extra         pages
if(isset($_POST['sow'])){ $sow = $_POST['sow']; } //site on web
$message ="
title = $title
name = $name
companyname = $companyname
mail = $mail
extra pages = $extrapages
site on web = $sow
";
//header
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
//mail code
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

html code:

```
                                <form action="" method="POST">
                                <em>Last name:</em></br>
                                <select name="title" id="title">
                                <option>Mr.</option>
                                <option>Mrs.</option>
                                <option>Dr.</option>
                                </select>
                                <input type="text" size="25" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Last name" required="required"><p /><br>
                                <em>company name:</em></br>
                                <input type="text" size="25" name="companyname" id="companyname" placeholder="Company Name" required="required"><p /><br>
                                <em>Email:</em></br>
                                <input type="text" size="25" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="email" required="required"><p /><br>
                                <em>how many extra pages:</em><br>
                                <select name="extrapages" id="extrapages">
                                <option>0</option>
                                <option>1</option>
                                <option>2</option>
                                <option>3</option>
                                <option>4</option>
                                <option>5</option>
                                <option>6</option>
                                <option>7</option>
                                <option>8</option>
                                <option>9</option>
                                </select><br><br>
                                <em>Would you like us to put your site on the internet?</em><br>
                                <input type="radio" name="sow" id="sow" value="Yes" required="required">Yes
                                <input type="radio" name="sow" id="sow" value="No" required="required">No<br><br>
                                <input type="Submit" value="Send!" name="submit">
                            </form>
```

Comment: sounds like some form of auto bot to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your form is set to run *every time the page loads*. You don't check to see if the form from submitted. You also have *absolutely no validation*.

To fix this wrap all of this code in an if statement that checks to see if the form has been submitted. You can check the `$_SERVER` superglobal which contains and key called `REQUEST_METHOD` which will tell you if the page was requested via POST (as is common when a form is submitted) or GET (as is common on a "typical" page load). If it's value is "POST" then the form was submitted and you can process the data, if not, ignore that code.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Let's not leave bots out of the equation neither ;-)